# Can't create object with variable inputted on construction - says "Expected a type specifier"

Tags: c++, object, types, constructor

I am having a problem with creating objects where the class has a variable as part of its constructor. It keeps telling me "expected a type specifier". Here is a simple example I copied from a basic tutorial to illustrate:

```
class TLine {
public:
    void setLength(double len);
    double getLength(void);
    TLine(double len);  // This is the constructor

private:
    double length;
};

TLine::TLine(double len) {
    cout << "Object is being created, length = " << len << endl;
    length = len;
}
void TLine::setLength(double len) {
    length = len;
}
double TLine::getLength(void) {
    return length;
}
```

If I follow that code directly with:

```
class Test2 {
public:
private:
    TLine testLineInClass(120.0);
};

TLine testline(12.0);
```

Only the second object creation for `TLine testline(12.0);` works. The `TLine testLineInClass(120.0);` gives an error on the `120.0`:

> Error (active)    E0079   expected a type specifier

Why would this not be working? Is there any correct way to create objects that require a variable inputted to them inside another class like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a class, you need to use `{}`, like this:

```
TLine testLineInClass {120.0};
```

Comment: No worries, glad it worked. Consider accepting the answer when you can.